# using a variable as array name in TCL script (array)

Tags: array, tcl

The question is about TCL Arrays.
In my TCL script,
**`variable1`** is a variable value obtained from other functions(value is something like `PATH_xyz`.)
**`variable2`** is another variable obtained from other calculations, whose value is something like `{3.5400 7.3200}`.

I want to:

```
set ${variable1}(modifyPt) {variable2}

puts ${variable1}(modifyPt)
```

How to do it correctly?

I tried

```
set ${variable1}(modifyPt) $variable2
```

output>>>: `4379.2160 13892.8270`

```
puts ${variable1}(modifyPt)
```

output>>>: `PATH_62_5474(modifyPt)`

(`PATH_62_5474` was stored in `variable1` at that point of execution)
I was expecting value of `PATH_62_5474(modifyPt)`, i.e., `4379.2160 13892.8270` at the second output above. also I tried

```
puts ${${xysp}(modifyPt)}
```

output>>>: `Error: can't read "${variable1": no such variable`

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend staying away from dynamic variable names. You can create a "compound" array key to keep it simple

```tcl
# setup
set variable1 PATH_xyz
set variable2 {3.5400 7.3200}

# store the data in an array named "data"
set data($variable1,modifyPt) $variable2

# extracting it
% puts $data($variable1,modifyPt)    ; # => 3.5400 7.3200

# print the array contents
parray data    ; # => data(PATH_xyz,modifyPt) = 3.5400 7.3200
```

You *can* use a dictionary with a dynamic variable name, but extracting data from the dictionary looks a bit weird:

```tcl
# store an empty dictionary in the variable "PATH_xyz"
set $variable1 [dict create]

# `dict set` takes a variable *name*
dict set $variable1 modifyPt $variable2

# `dict get` takes a variable *value*
dict get [set $variable1] modifyPt       ; # => 3.5400 7.3200
```

In a similar way, you can use arrays in the same awkward way:

```tcl
array set $variable1 [list modifyPt $variable2]
parray $variable1                    ; # => PATH_xyz(modifyPt) = 3.5400 7.3200
puts [set ${variable1}(modifyPt)]    ; # => 3.5400 7.3200
```

or the truly horrible

```tcl
puts [subst -nobackslashes -nocommands $${variable1}(modifyPt)]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand what you're after, but here are some examples of how to indirectly reference an array element in tcl:

```
% set array(key1) {value 1}
value 1
% set aname array
array
% set ${aname}(key2) {value 2}
value 2
% array get ${aname}
key {some value} key1 {value 1} key2 {value 2}

% set ${aname}(key2)
value 2
% set key key2
key2
% puts "<[set ${aname}($key)]>"
<value 2>
```

In your example, you can just use `set` instead of `puts`:

```
% set variable2 {3.5400 7.3200}
3.5400 7.3200
% set variable1 PATH_xyz
PATH_xyz
% set ${variable1}(modifyPt) $variable2
3.5400 7.3200
% set ${variable1}(modifyPt)
3.5400 7.3200
```

And just as above, you can use it in a `[...]` command substitution:

```
% puts "${variable1}\(modifyPt)={[set ${variable1}(modifyPt)]}"
PATH_xyz(modifyPt)={3.5400 7.3200}
```